# What is the domain of this function in 3 variables?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function
$$f(x, y, z)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+xyz.$$
Which is the domain of this function?

Certainly, we have to ask $(x, y, z)\neq(0, 0, 0)$ but also the points of the type
$$ (0, y, z), \ (x, 0, z), \ (x, y, 0), \ (0, 0, z), \ (x, 0, 0), \ (0, y,0)$$
are not allowed. How to write in an "easy" way?

I would say
$$D(f)=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : (x, y, z)\neq (0, 0, 0), ..\}$$
but I don't know how to continue. Could anyone please help me?

Finally, all these points to be excluded, consitute a straight line, a plane or something else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use $xyz\neq 0$

Comment: Or $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})^3$.

Comment: Or $x,y,z\neq0$ if you were working in a non-integral domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want any of $x,y$ or $z$ to vanish. Since $xyz$ vanishes if any one of the factors vanishes, then for no factor to vanish the product too must not vanish. (Another way to see this is to add the fractions, whose denominator will be $xyz.$)

Hence, the maximal domain is the set of all points in space except for those on the surfaces $xyz=0,$ namely the coordinate planes.

Comment: I am interested in your answer, but how to write the domain? And what means "coordinate planes"?

Comment: @C.Bishop The domain is in the last paragraph -- in symbols, that is the set $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathrm R^3|xyz\ne 0\}.$ The coordinate planes are all points in space satisfying the equations $x=0,y=0,z=0,$ just like the coordinate axes $x=0,y=0$ in two dimensions (i.e., in the plane).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Finally, we shoud say that $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(D(f))$, isn't it?

Comment: @C.Bishop If that means $f$ is smooth, I don't see why that is required here. You asked only for the domain, and it has been given.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
You've already found an answer by yourself. You can just set the domain of your function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ to
$$
\begin{align}
X
&= \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3 ~ | ~ x \neq 0 \land y \neq 0 \land z \neq 0 \}\\
&= \R^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3 ~ | ~ x = 0 \lor y = 0 \lor z = 0 \}\\
&= \R^3 \setminus \left[\left\{(x,y,z) \in \R^3 ~ | ~ x = 0\} \cup \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3 ~ | ~ y = 0\} \cup \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3 ~ | ~ z = 0\right\}\right]
\end{align}
$$
It constitutes an entire three-dimensional Euclidean space with the $x-y$, $y-z$, and $z-x$ planes being removed.

Meanwhile, the codomain should be $Y = \R$.

Answer (score -1):

For your first question consider labeling the domain:

$D(f)=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x,y,z \neq 0\}$.

The following is a response to your second question from the bottom of your post:

As $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ represents all of $3$-dimensional space, $D(f)$ is $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ without the points previously mentioned. The origin $(0,0,0)$ is removed, WLOG points of the form $(0,0,z)$ lie on one of the $3$ axes, so each axis is removed. WLOG points of the form $(0,y,z)$ represent an arbitrary point on the $xy$ plane. Altogether, we end up with $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ without the $xy$,$xz$,and $yz$ planes.

Comment: Haha, what are the downvotes for? The answer that is upvoted is saying the exact same thing, was written $30$ minutes after me, and using odd terminology to describe something more simply put another way as I have done. I made everything explicit, while they wrote "vanishes", maximal domain, etc, which are irrelevant terms to someone at the level of asking such a question in the first place.